# Can tomato essence be made with tomatoes only?

Tags: tomatoes

I've seen a few recipes for tomato essence and they all include a few other distinctly flavoured ingredients.  I understand the essence of something to be of that one item.  How can the tomato essences be so tomatoey when other ingredients are fennel, basil, onion, etc?

Comment: After a quick google, some recipe have only tomatoes, some have additional ingredients (maybe to enhance the flavor or the tomatoes?)

Comment: what words did you use for your search?

Comment: just "tomato essence"!  there's a result from Martha Stewart with only tomatoes.